# How do I remove special characters in an asp.net MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm running asp.net MVC razor. I'm trying to remove quotes from a string in my view.

so I'm returning this

```
  "<p><strong>test</strong</p>" 

and my wanting this

     <p><strong>test</strong></p>
```

here is what I've tried:

```
@foreach (var post in Model)
{
    var cont = post.postContent.Trim('"');

    <div class="post">
        <h2>@Html.ActionLink(post.postTitle, "Details", "Home", new { id = post.postId }, null)</h2>

         @cont

        <p>@post.postDate</p>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you seeing HTML encoded text (when you view the source) where `@Cont` is displayed?  If so, try

```
@Html.Raw(cont)
```